# nth-child not working on my code?

Tags: css, css-selectors

my problem is simple. I've put my code on this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/G79X9/61/

```
.historyContainer{
    margin-top: 45px;
    width: 856px;
    margin: 29px auto;
    }
    .depositContainer :nth-child(even)
    {
        background-color: green;
    }
    .depositContainer :nth-child(even)
    {
        background-color: red;
    }
    .withdrawContainer :nth-child(even)
    {
        background-color: red;
    }
    .withdrawContainer :nth-child(even)
    {
        background-color: green;
    }
    .offerHistory1{
        width: 50%;
        float: left;
        text-align: center;
        background-color: #cdc;
    }
    .offerHistory2{
        width: 50%;
        float: left;
        text-align: center;
        background-color: #dcd;
    }
    .depositHistory{
        width: 50%;
        float: left;
    }
    .withdrawHistory{
        width: 50%;
        float: right;
    }
```

I just want the divs background to be "stripped"(one with one color and the other with another color). I thought this should work but it isn't.

Comment: In JSFiddle you can **tidy up** your code! It's right from the *save* button.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So like this?

```
<div class="historyContainer">
  <div class="offerHistory1">Deposit</div>
  <div class="offerHistory2">Withdraw</div>
  <div class="depositHistory">
    <div class="depositContainer"><b>ID: 25 - Status: </b>Forbiden: Trade hold</div>
    <div class="depositContainer"><b>ID: 24 - Status: </b>Forbiden: Trade hold</div>
  </div>
  <div class="withdrawHistory">
    <div class="withdrawContainer"><b>ID: 38 - Status: </b>coins refunded</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS code...

```
.historyContainer{
    margin-top: 45px;
    width: 856px;
    margin: 29px auto;
}
.depositContainer:nth-child(even)
{
    background-color: green;
}
.depositContainer:nth-child(odd)
{
    background-color: red;
}
.withdrawContainer:nth-child(even)
{
    background-color: red;
}
.withdrawContainer:nth-child(odd)
{
    background-color: green;
}
.offerHistory1{
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #cdc;
}
.offerHistory2{
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #dcd;
}
.depositHistory{
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
}
.withdrawHistory{
    width: 50%;
    float: right;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jonathanzuniga/7kp131d9/

Comment: @MarcielFonseca You need to add even or odd. Not all even.

Comment: @MarcielFonseca I just removed the blank space between the classes and the pseudo selectors and replace the second `:nth-child(even)` with `:nth-child(odd)`.

Answer (score 3):

you have two mistakes in your code:

1.) Don't leave spaces before pseudo-classes: Not `.depositContainer :nth-child(even)`, but `.depositContainer:nth-child(even)`

2.) You have to swap between "odd" and "even" in the parenthesis after your pseudo-classes

Comment: Wow, how could I not notice that? Thank You!